# Shape.Child property returns False for copied groups

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.child%28v=office.14%29.aspx) `Shape.Child` is "msoTrue if the shape is a child shape or if all shapes in a shape range are child shapes of the same parent."

This seems to be valid for a newly created groups or a re-grouped object. However, if I create a group of a few objects (on an otherwise blank slide in PPT 2010) and **copy** this group I get

`ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes(1).GroupItems(1).Child = msoTrue`

`ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes(2).GroupItems(1).Child = msoFalse`

Seems like the `Child` property is reset for child shapes of the copy of the original group.

Do I have a corrupt installation or is this a bug (with a known fix/workaround)?

Comment: I added the best workaround I could find, but I would also be interested in an update if you found any other workaround...

Comment: Thanks for your input, nice idea. I have added another workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered this issue, so I *guess* it is a bug.

**Workaround**

The only workaround I found so far is to ungroup and regroup the group of interest:

```
Shape copiedGroup = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes(2); // this is the group whose children don't know they are children
Shape fixedGroup = copiedGroup.Ungroup().Regroup(); // now all children know their parent again
```

Using this fix, the children will return `msoTrue` for the `Child` property and the `ParentGroup` will return the group shape.

**Caveats**

If the group you are repairing was previously selected, it will be now be deselected.

Comment: Another word of warning: Ungroup().Regroup() removes many settings applied on the group level, e.g. shadow, 3-D rotation, animation. At least that's what I experienced with Office 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same problem on a different machine and NobodysNightmare also confirmed it which seems like strong evidence for a bug.

Another workaround that came to my mind would be iterating over all shapes like this. I don't really like the approach but it seems to work.

```
Function IsChild(s As Shape) As Boolean
    For i = 1 To s.Parent.Shapes.Count
        If s.Parent.Shapes(i).Type = msoGroup Then
            For j = 1 To s.Parent.Shapes(i).GroupItems.Count
                If s.Parent.Shapes(i).GroupItems(j) Is s Then IsChild = True
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found that when a grouped shape is copied, the copied one tends to lose 'Parent/Child' property or relation.
NobodysNightmare's workaround works great.
So when I copy a grouped shape, I do the following trick.

```
sub CopyShape()
    dim sld1 as Slide, sld2 as Slide
    dim shp as Shape

    Set sld1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set sld2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)    ' the target slide to copy the shape on
    Set shp = sld1.Shapes("myShape")            ' the target shape

    shp.Copy
    With sld2.Shapes.Paste
        'if it's a group, ungroup and regroup the shape and name it again as before
        If shp.Type = msoGroup Then .Ungroup.Regroup.Name = shp.Name
        'Now the copied shape has recovered it's Parent/Child property
    End With
end sub
```